# Prevent kernel modules  filesystems; (xfs,jfs,reiserfs) from loading

Tags: kernel

I noticed just about all the file system modules are loaded by default on boot - filesystems I'll never use. These include atleast:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
jfs                   182186  0 
xfs                   823190  0 
reiserfs              248223  0 
btrfs                 550402  0 
ufs                    75815  0 
qnx4                   17685  0 
hfsplus                84797  0 
minix                  36367  0 
ntfs                  101769  0
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent these being loaded ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can blacklist them in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` by adding `blacklist xfs` `blacklist reiserfs` etc. You can also create your own blacklist there. for example `blacklist-mine.conf`.

Still it's strange that all those are loaded. Have you started gparted before checking or are you on a live system maybe?

Comment: That seems to do the trick, although `sudo /sbin/update-initramfs -u` needs to be run as well, after altering  blacklist.conf

Answer (score 1):

One reason for these filesystem modules being loaded is down to a package called `os-prober` which is used by `grub-common` to detect other OSes on attached disks (specifically in `/usr/lib/os-probes/init/10filesystems`). This gets called by [grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) related packages and other system updates.

However the filesystem check (and the subsequent loading of the modules) can be disabled on a system by adding the following line to the grub config file `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

Then one needs to run the update-grub command to update /boot/grub/grub.cfg:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I find this method more useful than blacklisting. On my server I don't want other OSs anyway :-)